# How to make CMake build in CLion after changes in resource files

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

In a CLion project, I need some resources to be copied to the binary folder. They are GLSL shaders, so when I edit them, I want to be able to see the result. Unfortunately, CLion only rebuilds the project when there are changes to the source, so if I edit the GLSL files but leave the source files unchanged, CLion won't rebuild and thus the new files will not be copied to the binary directory. How do I fix this?

This is my code to move the files into the binary directory of the target OpenGL_Test:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET OpenGL_Test PRE_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/res 
    $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:OpenGL_Test>/res
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `add_custom_target` with `ALL` option, which will force CMake to copy the directory on every build:

```
add_custom_target(copy_shaders ALL
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory 
        "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/res" "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:OpenGL_Test>/res"
    COMMENT "Copy shaders to build tree"
    VERBATIM)
```

Comment: That gives me the following error:
Error:The inter-target dependency graph contains the following strongly connected component (cycle):
  "copy_shaders" of type UTILITY
    depends on "OpenGL_Test" (strong)
  "OpenGL_Test" of type EXECUTABLE
    depends on "copy_shaders" (strong)
At least one of these targets is not a STATIC_LIBRARY.  Cyclic dependencies are allowed only among static libraries.

Comment: Will it copy all files or only the ones that have been added/modified?